# Oracle Query output incorrect

Tags: sql, oracle

```
            CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_con(p_table_owner IN varchar2, p_table_name IN varchar2, p_result OUT sys_refcursor) AS BEGIN OPEN p_result
FOR
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type ='C' THEN
                         (SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 1, 'CHECK on single column', 'CHECK Table level')
                          FROM dba_cons_columns ucc2
                          WHERE ucc2.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                          AND ucc2.owner = uc.owner
                          AND ucc2.table_name = uc.table_name)
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  ELSE ''
              END AS constraint_type,
              uc.constraint_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
              uc.delete_rule AS "DELETE_ACTION",
              NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
              uc.status AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
              NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
              uc.search_condition AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
              NULL AS data_compression,
              NULL AS default_uid,
              NULL AS partition_qty,
              (SELECT LISTAGG(ucc1.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc1.column_name) 
                 FROM dba_cons_columns ucc1
                WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
                  AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
                  AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner) AS column_names
       FROM dba_constraints uc
       WHERE uc.OWNER = 'HR'
         AND uc.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
         );

 END;














SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type ='C' THEN
                         (SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 1, 'CHECK on single column', 'CHECK Table level')
                          FROM dba_cons_columns ucc2
                          WHERE ucc2.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                          AND ucc2.owner = uc.owner
                          AND ucc2.table_name = uc.table_name)
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  ELSE ''
              END AS constraint_type,
              uc.constraint_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
              uc.delete_rule AS "DELETE_ACTION",
              NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
              uc.status AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
              NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
              uc.search_condition AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
              NULL AS data_compression,
              NULL AS default_uid,
              NULL AS partition_qty,
              (SELECT LISTAGG(ucc1.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc1.column_name) 
                 FROM dba_cons_columns ucc1
                WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
                  AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
                  AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner) AS column_names
       FROM dba_constraints uc
       WHERE uc.OWNER = 'HR'
         AND uc.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
         );



         SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type ='C' THEN
                         (SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 1, 'CHECK on single column', 'CHECK Table level')
                          FROM dba_cons_columns ucc2
                          WHERE ucc2.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                          AND ucc2.owner = uc.owner
                          AND ucc2.table_name = uc.table_name)
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  ELSE ''
              END AS constraint_type,
              uc.constraint_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
              uc.delete_rule AS "DELETE_ACTION",
              NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
              uc.status AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
              NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
              uc.search_condition AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
              NULL AS data_compression,
              NULL AS default_uid,
              NULL AS partition_qty,
              (SELECT LISTAGG(ucc1.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc1.column_name) 
                 FROM dba_cons_columns ucc1
                WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
                  AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
                  AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner) AS column_names
       FROM dba_constraints uc
       WHERE uc.OWNER = 'HR'
         AND uc.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
         );


         SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type ='C' THEN
                         (SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 1, 'CHECK on column ' || LISTAGG(ucc2.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc2.column_name) , 'CHECK Table level')
                          FROM dba_cons_columns ucc2
                          WHERE ucc2.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                          AND ucc2.owner = uc.owner
                          AND ucc2.table_name = uc.table_name)
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY (clustered)'
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'DEFAULT' THEN 'DEFAULT on column ' || ucc1.column_name
                  ELSE ''
              END AS constraint_type,
              uc.constraint_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
              uc.delete_rule AS "DELETE_ACTION",
              NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
              uc.status AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
              NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
              uc.search_condition AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
              NULL AS data_compression,
              NULL AS default_uid,
              NULL AS partition_qty,
              (SELECT LISTAGG(ucc1.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc1.column_name) 
                 FROM dba_cons_columns ucc1
                WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
                  AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
                  AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner) AS column_names
       FROM dba_constraints uc,
       dba_cons_columns ucc1
       WHERE   uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
     AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
     AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner
       AND   uc.OWNER = 'HR'
         AND uc.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'

          UNION ALL SELECT 'DEFAULT on column ' || cc.column_name,
                    'DF_' || cc.column_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                    NULL AS "DELETE_ACTION",
                    NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
                    NULL AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
                    NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
                    cc.data_default AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
                    NULL AS data_compression,
                    NULL AS default_uid,
                    NULL AS partition_qty,
                    cc.column_name
   FROM dba_tab_columns cc
   WHERE cc.owner='HR'
     AND cc.table_name='EMP'
     AND data_default IS NOT NULL );




     SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type ='C' THEN
                         (SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 1, 'CHECK on column ' || LISTAGG(ucc2.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc2.column_name) , 'CHECK Table level')
                          FROM dba_cons_columns ucc2
                          WHERE ucc2.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                          AND ucc2.owner = uc.owner
                          AND ucc2.table_name = uc.table_name)
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY (clustered)'
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'DEFAULT' THEN 'DEFAULT on column ' 
                  ELSE ''
              END AS constraint_type,
              uc.constraint_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
              uc.delete_rule AS "DELETE_ACTION",
              NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
              uc.status AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
              NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
              uc.search_condition AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
              NULL AS data_compression,
              NULL AS default_uid,
              NULL AS partition_qty,
              (SELECT LISTAGG(ucc1.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc1.column_name) 
                 FROM dba_cons_columns ucc1
                WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
                  AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
                  AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner) AS column_names
       FROM dba_constraints uc

       WHERE   
      uc.OWNER = 'HR'
         AND uc.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'

          UNION ALL SELECT 'DEFAULT on column ' || cc.column_name,
                    'DF_' || cc.column_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                    NULL AS "DELETE_ACTION",
                    NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
                    NULL AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
                    NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
                    cc.data_default AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
                    NULL AS data_compression,
                    NULL AS default_uid,
                    NULL AS partition_qty,
                    cc.column_name
   FROM dba_tab_columns cc
   WHERE cc.owner='HR'
     AND cc.table_name='EMP'
     AND data_default IS NOT NULL );



     SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type ='C' THEN
                         (SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 1, 'CHECK on column ' || LISTAGG(ucc2.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc2.column_name) , 'CHECK Table level')
                          FROM dba_cons_columns ucc2
                          WHERE ucc2.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                          AND ucc2.owner = uc.owner
                          AND ucc2.table_name = uc.table_name)
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY (clustered)'
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'DEFAULT' THEN 'DEFAULT on column ' 
                  ELSE ''
              END AS constraint_type,
              uc.constraint_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
              uc.delete_rule AS "DELETE_ACTION",
              NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
              uc.status AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
              NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
              uc.search_condition AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
              NULL AS data_compression,
              NULL AS default_uid,
              NULL AS partition_qty,
              (SELECT LISTAGG(ucc1.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc1.column_name) 
                 FROM dba_cons_columns ucc1
                WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
                  AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
                  AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner) AS column_names
       FROM dba_constraints uc

       WHERE   
      uc.OWNER = 'HR'
         AND uc.TABLE_NAME = 'T'

          UNION ALL SELECT 'DEFAULT on column ' || cc.column_name,
                    'DF_' || cc.column_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                    NULL AS "DELETE_ACTION",
                    NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
                    NULL AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
                    NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
                    cc.data_default AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
                    NULL AS data_compression,
                    NULL AS default_uid,
                    NULL AS partition_qty,
                    cc.column_name
   FROM dba_tab_columns cc
   WHERE cc.owner='HR'
     AND cc.table_name='T'
     AND data_default IS NOT NULL );
```

For check constraint(table level like BONUS_CK)...it should display data only in one row with comma-separated column names...

like bonus,tax

Now it displays 2 rows for table level constraint i.e bonus_ck 
Also query should work with all versions(10g,11g,12c)

Please help with eliminating this duplicate row for table level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through your query, there are a few things that I would change.

Firstly, at the bottom, you have a join between `dba_constraints` and `dba_cons_columns`.  This will cause your query to have one row for each column of a multi-column constraint.  If you don't want this, you will have to remove `dba_cons_columns` from the main part of your query.  In situations similar to this, another option would be to keep the join on `dba_cons_columns` and add a `GROUP BY` containing all columns in `dba_constraints` that you were selecting from.  However, `search_condition` is a `LONG` and you can't `GROUP BY` a `LONG` column.

If you want a comma-separated list of column names, use the `LISTAGG` function.  For example, to get the list of columns in a constraint, you could use the following in a subquery:

```
              SELECT LISTAGG(ucc1.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc1.column_name) 
                 FROM dba_cons_columns ucc1
                WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
                  AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
                  AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner
```

`LISTAGG` concatenates together all values grouped into a single row.

Similarly, to detect whether you have a multi-column or single-column check constraint, you need another subquery on `dba_cons_columns`.  You are presently attempting to use two different `WHEN` clauses in your `CASE` expression to do this: I would suggest using just the one: write `WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'C' THEN ...` and then have a subquery that counts up the number of columns in the constraint and shows either single-column or multi-column as appropriate.

Finally, please note that Oracle is not SQL Server.  It seems you are using a couple of terms from SQL Server that do not exist in Oracle.  Remove the text 'clustered': there is no such terminology in Oracle.  (Oracle does have index-organized tables but I've never used them.)  Also get rid of the line `WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'DEFAULT' ...`, as default values for columns in Oracle are not set using constraints.

I ended up with the following, which appears to do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type ='C' THEN
                         (SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 1, 'CHECK on single column', 'CHECK Table level')
                          FROM dba_cons_columns ucc2
                          WHERE ucc2.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                          AND ucc2.owner = uc.owner
                          AND ucc2.table_name = uc.table_name)
                  WHEN uc.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  ELSE ''
              END AS constraint_type,
              uc.constraint_name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
              uc.delete_rule AS "DELETE_ACTION",
              NULL AS "UPDATE_ACTION",
              uc.status AS "STATUS_ENABLED",
              NULL AS "STATUS_FOR_REPLICATION",
              uc.search_condition AS "CONSTRAINT_KEYS",
              NULL AS data_compression,
              NULL AS default_uid,
              NULL AS partition_qty,
              (SELECT LISTAGG(ucc1.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc1.column_name) 
                 FROM dba_cons_columns ucc1
                WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
                  AND uc.table_name = ucc1.table_name
                  AND uc.owner = ucc1.owner) AS column_names
       FROM dba_constraints uc
       WHERE uc.OWNER = 'HR'
         AND uc.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
         );
```

I decided to change `CHECK on column ...` to `CHECK on single column` because the single column name is elsewhere in the query and it didn't seem worth repeating it.  You can always put a `LISTAGG` expression in there to get the column name out.

Comment: Thanks Luke...I have edited your shared query finally with all of my expectations and solved them..thanks